# How to decodeURIComponent? (ex: "%2F%3F%26%3D" -> "/?&=")

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

How to convert this

```
qqqq%2Fwwww%3Feeee%26rrrr%3Dtttt
```

to this

```
qqqq/wwww?eeee&rrrr=tttt
```

?

Is there easy way to decode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have a URI *encoding* library function, `Uri.EscapeDataString` but we don't have an inverse to decode (which might have been an oversight). Feel free to suggest this feature at https://ideas.powerbi.com

---

Writing your own is a little more complicated than text replace over "%" if there's any non-ASCII characters.

Here's an M implementation that builds up the bytes then converts to text as  UTF-8 binary:

```
let
    InputData = Csv.Document("a=b
=ab
ab=
abc☃def"),

    Uri.UnescapeDataString = (data as text) as text => let 
        ToList = Text.ToList(data),
        Accumulate = List.Accumulate(ToList, [ Bytes = {} ], (state, current) => 
            let
                HexString = state[HexString]?,
                NextHexString = HexString & current,
                NextState = if HexString <> null
                  then if Text.Length(NextHexString) = 2
                      then [ Bytes = state[Bytes] & Binary.ToList(Binary.FromText(NextHexString, BinaryEncoding.Hex)) ]
                      else [ HexString = NextHexString, Bytes = state[Bytes] ]
                  else if current = "%"
                      then [ HexString = "", Bytes = state[Bytes] ]
                  else [ Bytes = state[Bytes] & { Character.ToNumber(current) } ]
            in
                NextState),
        FromBinary = Text.FromBinary(Binary.FromList(Accumulate[Bytes]))
      in
        FromBinary,

    AddEscaped = Table.AddColumn(InputData, "Escaped", each Uri.EscapeDataString([Column1])),

    AddUnescaped = Table.AddColumn(AddEscaped, "Custom", each Uri.UnescapeDataString([Escaped]))
in
    AddUnescaped
```

---

(I'm kind of proud of the above, but I thought of an easier way, if you know that all the data is properly encoded.)

You could concatenate the string into a URL and leverage the URL decoding feature of `Uri.Parts` like:

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString = (data as text) as text => 
    Uri.Parts("http://whatever?a=" & data)[Query][a],
```

Comment: So Uri.Parts has a URL decoding feature - who knew? Thanks Carl for another M gem, sadly undocumented ... Can you add that info to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260886.aspx , perhaps with a more complete example as well?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MikeHoney, we've added this to the MSDN documentation and it will come out with the upcoming product release. If you have other documentation ideas, keep them coming :)

Comment: Great technique! I've tried using this technique with other things, but it turns out that `Web.Page("<script>document.write(navigator.appName + ' ' + navigator.appVersion)</script>")` reveals that even in 2022, Excel's PowerQuery web engine is **Internet Explorer 4.0** so the workaround I was attempting by using HTMLElement.textContent can't work because IE didn't support it back in 1997!

Answer (score 0):

Small extension to @MikeHoney code.
I wanted to Decode the full URI in 1 go:

```
// Uri.Decode()
// Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/uri-parts
// Encoded+Decoded "?" & "&" to non-URI chars so Uri.Parts() could convert entire URI in 1 go.
    Uri.Decode = (url as text) as text => 
        let t1 = Text.Replace (url, "?", Character.FromNumber (29) ), // ? -> <group separator> 
            t2 = Text.Replace (t1, "&", Character.FromNumber (30) ), // & -> <record separator>
            t3 = Uri.Parts("http://foo?a=" & t2)[Query][a],
            t4 = Text.Replace(t3, Character.FromNumber (29), "?" ),
            decoded = Text.Replace(t4, Character.FromNumber (30), "&" )
        in decoded,
```